# Okami sumie style rendering algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, graphics, 3d, rendering

Hey so I was wondering if anyone has any reading suggestions for papers/algorithms on how to render scenes in the style that was used for the video game Okami.

I've done some searching on my own and have found some "sumie" style papers but the algorithms presented there are black and white and I'm looking for something with color.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Non-photorealistic rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-photorealistic_rendering). There are dozens of algorithms, I can't tell you which one is used in the game exactly, it might be more algorithms together. Anyway, you may find some algorithms and techniques on [Stylized Depiction in Computer Graphics](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/npr/) and by searching on google..